# Using sparse tensor values in loss

Tags: pytorch, sparse-matrix

I generate a sparse matrix:

```
A = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(np.transpose(IJ),V)
```

where `IJ` is a `n`-by-`2` list of ij indices, and `V` is a 1D vector of parameters.

I then try to backprop a simple loss:

```
loss = A[0,0]**2
loss.backward()
```

This leads to the error

```
Function SelectBackward0 returned an invalid gradient at index 0 - expected layout Sparse but got Strided
```

Since this seems like the most basic loss that one can define on a sparse tensor, am I to understand pytorch does not support optimization of sparse tensors? Or is there somewhere else in my code I should be looking at?